# I am looking for a reporting solution for my project

Tags: c#, .net, report, reporting

My sql database includes only one to many relationships as follows:

Parent --> Child 1 --> Child 2 --> Child 3
Every one parent data may have 0 or more child data.

I tried reports designer 3.0 but it did not listed data that have no "child 3" data for the above case. And I could not find any resources to solve this.

I do not need any effects or smt. What I want is a very simple reporting tool which is able to query relational sql databases, list them like this:

```
Parent.Name[1]

Child1.Name[1]

Child2.Name[1]

Child3.Name[1]  Child3.valuea[1]  Child3.valueb[1]
Child3.Name[2]  Child3.valuea[2]  Child3.valueb[2]
Child3.Name[3]  Child3.valuea[3]  Child3.valueb[3]

Child2.Name[2]
.
.
.
etc
```

and export to excel file. Free applications are prefered but the ones with the trial verions are also good for me.
THX

Comment: Have you searched for anything? Do you only want to import data from a database to excel, because in that case you can accomplish that using excel alone, by using datasources.

Comment: That has been a tremendous enlightment for me. I have learned about PowerPivot for excel which gives what I want. However I need to implement the report to my winforms application (user pick a "project" and gets report of it with a button). So I send a "projectID" to the reporter and it generates report for the "project". Can I achieve this with this excel method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is only for one report, it doesn't make sense to use any reporting tools.

I don't know how the project is implemented, but try looking at the the following options since they are professional and can be used in enterprise systems.

1. Core java with JSF libraries (Such as PrimeFaces)
2. JSP
3. I-32 form solutions (easiest)